# sql oracle sysdate: ignore weekends

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, sysdate

I am using this code in my where:

```
and table.datum >= sysdate-7
and table.datum <= sysdate
```

It shows data from the last 7 days - I want to add that it ignores weekends (Saturday and Sunday) - I checked the Internet but nothing works for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Between and add this where statement.

```
AND table.datum BETWEEN sysdate-7 and sysdate
AND TO_CHAR(to_date(substr(table.datum,1,10), 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
                         'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('1', '7')
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea to convert a `VARCHAR` to a `DATE` and then back to `VARCHAR` again.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from @Matt is not error proof. Result of `TO_CHAR(..., 'D'` depends on `NLS_TERRITORY` which can be different on each session. 
Since the TO seems to be German (using `DATUM` as date expression) I am even surprised that solution from Matt works on his machine.

See this test case:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'AMERICA';

WITH d AS 
    (SELECT DATE '2015-03-01' + LEVEL AS datum FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31)
SELECT TO_CHAR(datum, 'yyyy-mm-dd fmDay')
FROM d
WHERE TO_CHAR(datum, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('1', '7')
    AND datum BETWEEN SYSDATE-7 AND SYSDATE;

TO_CHAR(DATUM,'YYYY-MM-DDFMDAY')
2015-03-18 Wednesday
2015-03-19 Thursday
2015-03-20 Friday
2015-03-23 Monday
2015-03-24 Tuesday


ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'GERMANY';

WITH d AS 
    (SELECT DATE '2015-03-01' + LEVEL AS datum FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31)
SELECT TO_CHAR(datum, 'yyyy-mm-dd fmDay')
FROM d
WHERE TO_CHAR(datum, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('1', '7')
    AND datum BETWEEN SYSDATE-7 AND SYSDATE;

TO_CHAR(DATUM,'YYYY-MM-DDFMDAY')
2015-03-18 Wednesday
2015-03-19 Thursday
2015-03-20 Friday
2015-03-21 Saturday
2015-03-24 Tuesday
```

More secure is to use `Dy` or `fmDay` format

```
WITH d AS 
    (SELECT DATE '2015-03-01' + LEVEL AS datum FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31)
SELECT TO_CHAR(datum, 'yyyy-mm-dd fmDay')
FROM d
WHERE TO_CHAR(datum, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') NOT IN ('Sun', 'Mon')
    AND datum BETWEEN SYSDATE-7 AND SYSDATE;
```